# How to change GlusterFS replica 2 to replica 3 with arbiter 1?

Tags: glusterfs

GlusterFS 3.7 introduced arbiter volume which it is a 3-way replication where the third brick is the arbiter.

How does one change from 2-way replication to 3-way replication with arbiter?

I could not find any documentation of changing running replica 2 volume to arbiter volume.

Reference:
https://gluster.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Administrator%20Guide/arbiter-volumes-and-quorum/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just sent the patch http://review.gluster.org/#/c/14502/ to add this functionality. If everything goes well, it should make it to the 3.8 release.

Comment: Thanks @itisravi! :)